# Storing ab object in a class library

Tags: c#

I have an object (a system GUID) I need to use repeatedly in my class library. I would like to store it somewhere. Whats the best way to do that? Im thinking i could serialize and deserialize the object but it dosent seem like the simplest solution.

Comment: "Store it somewhere" is rather vague. Does it need to persist between application startups? Computer startups? Something else?

Comment: Between application startups.

Comment: @Oded "Store it somewhere" is rather vague because Im asking for advice on where to store it.

Comment: yes, and without having a clear idea of _why_ you need to, it is difficult to give an answer that will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert it into a string, store this in your Resources/App.Confing/Whatever (even as a constant in some of your classes) and use the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ff78dc.aspx) of Guid with the string overload to load it.